# Change page on button click not listbox click Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, button

I have a list box and a button next to the list box. I'm trying to make the page change on the list box item that's selected. So, an item is selected then the button is pressed, which changes the page and passes the item into a search page.

At the moment, as I press a button in the List Box, it changes the page. It doesn't wait for you to press the button. The HTML provided is here

```
  <div style="margin:auto">
<h3 style="text-align:center">
 Or Search By Home Town: 
 <select id="myTown">
 <?php 
   include("scripts/dbconnect.php"); 
   include("scripts/lists.php"); 
 ?>
 </select>
 <input type="button" value="Search" />
</h3>
```

The selector I have is here :

```
      $('#myTown option').click(getTown);
function getTown(){
 var town=$(this).val();
 window.location='searchresults.php?querystring='+town+'&querydesc=Town= &querytype=4';}
```

I think "this" should change to button or something along those lines.

or the selector "option" needs to be changed. if anyone can help that'd be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just assign an event handler for the button:

```
$('#button1').click(function() { getTown(); });

<input id="button1" type="button" value="Search" />
```

and then get rid of the event handler for the option tag

update (if you can't change html):

```
$('#myTown').parent().find('input').click(function() { getTown(); });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the HTML, can only change the jquery. Which means I can't change the ID of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use select box change event. change will trigger every time you change option.

```
 <input type="button" id="btn" value="Search" />


 $('#btn').click(getTown);
function getTown(){
 var town=$("#myTown").val();
 window.location='searchresults.php?querystring='+town+'&querydesc=Town= &querytype=4';}
```

Comment: This still changes when you press any of the items in the list box, where as I'd like it so you'd change page when the button is pressed.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read you question completely. I make the change . this should help you.